# Symfony2 - trying to keep bundles apart

Tags: php, symfony

I'm fairly new to Symfony2...

My problem:

How do I make sure bundles don't reference each other directly? I am trying to keep things as loosely coupled as possible; there can be exceptions and dependencies where needed, but I don't want to start building many bundles that reference one another.

Example:

While adding some simple CMS functionality to a site, I currently have these bundles:

- src: AdminBundle - uses Sonata Admin
- src: MainBundle - contains the main site and the Doctrine entity classes
- vendor: Sonata-Admin

So the AdminBundle needs to work with the entities provided within the MainBundle. As a result, in src/AdminBundle/Resources/config/services.yml I have entries like this:

```
services:
    pwn.admin.page:
        class: Pwn\AdminBundle\Admin\PageAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Content, label: Pages }
        arguments: [null, Pwn\MainBundle\Entity\Page, null]
```

The reference to MainBundle is what I'm trying to avoid. I want it to be easy to specify a different ORM object if needed, perhaps even from another bundle.

Overall, I'm trying to make it so that only the files in app/config/ glue all the components together. Although, in some cases I guess it's ok for a bundle to have a tight one-way dependency: my AdminBundle depends on Sonata Admin.

Options:

1. Move the entire services definition from src/AdminBundle/Resources/config/services.yml to app/config/config.yml (or a perhaps an included file like config_admin.yml). However, this seems like it might bloat up the config a bit  and/or lead to repetition in the service definitions. Are these significant problems?
2. Change the arguments line to use a parameter, e.g. 
   arguments: [null, %admin.entity.page%, null]
   The parameter for each entity can then be specified in app/config/config.yml. However, if I do this extensively then I could end up with a large number of entries in the "parameters" namespace, and I don't think that is its intended use?
3. Create a new service with a service container extension as explained here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#importing-configuration-via-container-extensions. To be honest I'm not sure how such a service could then register itself in the sonata.admin group and get picked up by Sonata Admin.
4. Leave the whole definition in Resources/config/services.yml and be happy that it's still relatively easy to make changes there in future.

Any help/comments much appreciated; if my whole approach is wrong then please say. :)

Comment: I think #2 is the way to go.  If you look in the S2 framework classes/configs you will see that that is exactly what they do.

Comment: Thanks. I went with the solution here in the end (basically a variant of the option you suggested): http://tinyurl.com/9cdywyh